# PHP/MySQL with encoding of inserts

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I am having a problem with a MySQL database and PHP. These are older versions, it is MySQL 4.1.2 and PHP 4.3.

The problem is on some values I am inserting into the database, somewhere, they are being converted to UTF8. So when I run another query on the same data, it has to convert parts of it, like the Update query below.

```
UPDATE `course_pages` 
SET `body` = '<p>dfhdgfhdfhg</p>', `last_modified` = NOW() 
WHERE CONVERT(`course_pages`.`assigned_id` USING utf8) = 'testCourseForEditor'
AND `course_pages`.`page` = 1 LIMIT 1;
```

The insert query I ran from PHP was:

```
INSERT INTO " . $this->course_page_table . "
        SET
            assigned_id             = '" . $this->assigned_id . "',
            page                    =  " . $this->page . ",
            body                    = '" . $this->body . "',
            last_modified           = NOW()";
```

The table I am working with has its columns collation set to "latin1_swedish_ci". This was set before I ever started working on the server so I don't want to change it. I have been working with this server for over a year and never ran into this problem. I just started using Aptana Studio 3 yesterday, but nothing like this has happened until now.

Comment: So you want it to be set to `latin1_swedish_ci` every time you insert into the table?

Comment: *"some values ..., somewhere."* don't suppose you want to supply specifics

Comment: What I mean by that is it looks like not all of the values are being coverted to utf8 and by somwhere, I meant, I do know where this conversion is happening. Is PHP doing it or is the MySQL causing it?

Comment: Both MySQL and PHP are seriously outdated. Don't attract hackers to your server, just upgrade it.

Comment: Titanium, I want it to be latin1_swedish_ci so MySQL isn't adding the CONVERT functions to me queries. The top query was pulled from PHPMyAdmin. I just don't understand why this never happened before.

Comment: Upgrades are coming, but this is what I have to work with right now.

Comment: After some more checking, I realized this has nothing to do with PHP and my code. I have tried the same inserts using PHPMyAdmin and the MySQL command line and the same problem still occurs. It is only occurring with the assigned_id field too.